# Задача на нахождение в числе подчисла 33

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Не получается сделать задачу на C++

> Дано число N. Требуется определить, есть ли в данном числе две тройки,
>   идущие подряд. c++

Comment: В какой системе счисления?

Comment: @Yaant отличный вопрос ))

Answer (score 3):

```
while(N)
{
    if (N%100 == 33) return true;
    N /= 10;
}
return false;
```

Вариант:

```
return to_string(N).find("33") != string::npos;
```